# Read item from keychain right after creating

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra, keychain

I'm working with custom keychain in my application and I have problems with reading keychain item right after adding new one. This is code example:

```
let path = "/tmp/testkeychain_48"
let password = "password"
let serviceName = "service"
let account = "account"
let data = "data".data(using: .utf8)
var keychain: SecKeychain? = nil

var status = SecKeychainCreate(path, UInt32(password.characters.count), password, false, nil, &keychain)
assert(status == errSecSuccess)

var query: [String: AnyObject] = [
    kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
    kSecAttrService as String: serviceName as AnyObject,
    kSecAttrAccount as String: account as AnyObject,
    kSecValueData as String: data as AnyObject,
    kSecUseKeychain as String: keychain as AnyObject,
]

var item: CFTypeRef? = nil
status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, &item)
assert(status == errSecSuccess)
assert(item != nil)

query = [
    kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
    kSecAttrService as String: serviceName as AnyObject,
    kSecAttrAccount as String: account as AnyObject,
    kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitAll as AnyObject,
    kSecUseKeychain as String: keychain as AnyObject,
]

status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &item)
assert(status == errSecSuccess)
assert(item != nil)

try? FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: path)
```

`SecItemAdd(_:_)` returns success but `SecItemCopyMatching(_:_)` fails with error `The specified item could not be found in the keychain`. With default keychain all works correctly.

Comment: Can `kSecUseKeychain` be used with `SecItemCopyMatching`? `kSecMatchSearchList` works.

Comment: You are right, `kSecMatchSearchList` works. Thanks! Interesting that if you add newly created keychain to Keychain Access then `kSecUseKeychain` works as well. But I think `SecItemCopyMatching` ignores `kSecUseKeychain` and search through all keychains in Keychain Access.